# What is the proper way to deprecate a sub module in maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project having child projects.

Sample representation:

```
parent 

  core
   -src
   -pom.xml

  projA
   -src
   -pom.xml

  projB

    projB1 
     -src
     -pom.xml

    projB2
     -src
     -pom.xml

  projC
   -src
   -pom.xml

pom.xml (parent pom)
```

This is an open-source project. In the next release, **I want to deprecate  `projB2`**. I don't want to increase it's version.

How should I do it?

---

To further clarify, say all of my projects(*`core`, `projA`, `projB1`, `projB2`, `projC`*) are at version 1.2.

In next release, I want to increase the version of `core`, `projA`, `projB1`, `projC` to 1.3 and `projB2` to remain at 1.2 as this is the deprecated project.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to this is the `class relocation` in Maven. Please read the relocation part of the page, whose link is below.

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_relocation

In addition to this, somebody asked a similar question to you. The comments in the link would also help you find out a solution.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5604